# Can't compile 2.2 to 2.3 Migration

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I have been fighting with this for the past few hours and I haven't made any headway at all. It seems no matter what I do, I keep getting the same error.

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/Project$
```

My build.sbt

```
name := "appname"

version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  jdbc,
  anorm,
  cache,
  filters,
  "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc4",
  "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
  "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
  "org.webjars" % "foundation" % "5.3.0",
  "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "0.3.16"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).enablePlugins(PlayScala)

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
```

I have also tried this build.sbt

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

 val appName = "appname"
 val appVersion = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

 val appDependencies ++= Seq(
    jdbc,
    anorm,
    cache,
    filters,
    "org.postgresql" % "postgresql" % "9.3-1100-jdbc4",
    "org.mindrot" % "jbcrypt" % "0.3m",
    "org.webjars" %% "webjars-play" % "2.3.0-2",
    "org.webjars" % "foundation" % "5.3.0",
    "org.scalaj" %% "scalaj-http" % "0.3.16"
  )

 val main = Project(appName, file(".")).enablePlugins(play.PlayScala).settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.10.4",
    version := appVersion,
    libraryDependencies ++= appDependencies
  )
}
```

As well as different tweaks and modifications. Always the same error. The build.properties is set to `sbt.version=0.13.5`

plugins.sbt

```
logLevel := Level.Debug

// The Typesafe repository
resolvers += "Typesafe repository" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/"

// Use the Play sbt plugin for Play projects
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.3.4")
```

After running Patrick Mahoney's suggestion and making sure I removed the import.

### Errors:

```
[error] java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: play/Project$
[error] Use 'last' for the full log.
Project loading failed: (r)etry, (q)uit, (l)ast, or (i)gnore? q
me@me-desktop:~/Projects/appname$ sbt --version
   sbt launcher version 0.13.6
me@me-desktop:~/Projects/appname$ find . | grep -r "play.Project"
me@me-desktop:~/Projects/appname$ find . | grep -r "play/Project"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to James and Patrick, but I found the problem. The problem was in the `activator-sbt-echo-play-shim.sbt` file in the `/project` directory.

It contained the following:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "0.1.1.3")
```

I created a second blank 2.3.4 app using Activator and it's `activator-sbt-echo-play-shim.sbt` listed:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5")
```

So I updated the one in my project to 1.5 and deleted the idea and eclipse .sbts for good measure and the app was finally able to compile. It auotmatically updated the above to:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.github.mpeltonen" % "sbt-idea" % "1.5.2")
```

Now I have other, more expected, issues I need to work out (like anorm). But I'm now able to compile it and get those errors to start working them out. I did not think these files were part of the activator/sbt compile, but I guess they were. I thought they were for debugging. But they made the difference and the changes above worked.

Thanks again to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 3):

Try cleaning your build project compiled outputs:

```
rm -rf project/target
```

or

```
$> sbt "reload plugins" clean
```

(in addition to applying James' answer)

Comment: As much as we appreciate the input, this is normally the kind of addition comments are for. I know it's kind of a bother not being able to comment while you gather the appropriate rep, but 50 rep is pretty close, you'll see soon enough :)

Comment: @Julldar actually, this may be the answer to my question. I haven't tried this yet. I did remove the project/target at one point (but put it back), but I never ran the clean command. But, I won't be able to try it until later this afternoon. It makes sense, because I checked that I removed all references to `play.Project._` several times.

Comment: @badatscala my bad then, I really saw this as an addition to James answer as opposed to an answer of it's own.  Sorry :D

Comment: Thanks for helping Patrick. This did nothing either. I have no idea wth is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've updated `project/build.properties` to have sbt version 0.13.5.  Then, remove `import play.Project._`, it's not needed.  That should work.

Comment: That was my first thought, because that's basically what the error says. But it does not work. I've searched my code for any other instances but didn't find any.

Comment: Same error, removing it made no difference. I found the issue, it was in the `activator-sbt-echo-play-shim.sbt` file.